# Is pain lessened by swearing?

Tags: medical-science, psychology, biology

[image]

Earlier today, during one of my many home improvement projects ("experiments" may be a more appropriate term) I struck my thumb with a hammer.

Without thinking, I released a reflexive string of profanity which quite possibly made my dog blush and certainly caused my neighbors to stand up and take notice. However, by the time the last four-letter word escaped my lips, the pain had faded, and in fact was almost gone.

Almost everyone can remember this happening or has at least observed it a few times.

That swearing after an injury can ease pain seems to be a commonly held belief (at least in America), but is it really more effective than just screaming, or simply remaining silent?

**Is there evidence that swearing can either lessen the pain of acute injuries or our perception of it?  Has this been studied?**

Comment: Excellent question. Always works for me...data would be cool.

Comment: Tested by the __Mythbusters__ in [No Pain, No Gain](http://dsc.discovery.com/fansites/mythbusters/db/human-body/cursing-and-pain.html)

Comment: @Oliver_C That's the first thought I had when I saw this question.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if it is swearing itself or the vocalizations that helped reduce pain intensity. E.g. would yelling out pleasantries - *slam* "WHAT A WONDERFUL WONDERFUL DAY" - with the same intensity have the same effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image] <sub>([Image Source](http://dsc.discovery.com/tv/mythbusters/))</sub>

I think [The Mythbusters](http://dsc.discovery.com/videos/mythbusters-adam-savage-swearing-test.html) based their experiment on this:

**[Swearing helps to reduce pain](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/8147170.stm)**

> Dr Richard Stephens, from [Keele's](http://www.keele.ac.uk/)
>   school of psychology, came up with the
>   idea for the study after swearing when
>   he accidentally hit his thumb with a
>   hammer as he built a garden shed.
>
> **He recruited 64 volunteers to take part and each individual was asked to
>   submerge their hand in a tub of
>   freezing water for as long as possible**...
>
> ...
>   **the researchers found that the
>   volunteers were able to keep their
>   hands plunged in the ice water for a
>   longer period of time when repeating
>   [a] swear word.**
>
> While it is not clear how or why this
>   link exists, the team believes that
>   the pain-lessening effect occurs
>   because swearing triggers our natural
>   'fight-or-flight' response.

[Here](http://journals.lww.com/neuroreport/Abstract/publishahead/Swearing_as_a_response_to_pain.99989.aspx) is the abstract of the original paper.

Comment: Had I done a little more researchbefore posting this, I would have found that they were awarded an igNobel for that paper.

Comment: This is purely speculation, but I'd imagine that swearing releases adrenalin and increases the heart rate, both of which are known factors in reduced pain reception.